# Using React with or without jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and not sure how but I was able to run a simple app without jsx, my js file start like that:

```
class TestClass extends React.Component
```

Do I need to use jsx or can I use js file instead?
What are the benefits of using jsx file?

My html file contains the following scripts:

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.5.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
```

Is that the right way of using React in a production environment?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not the right way for prod as converting es6 and jsx at runtime is slow and requires extra libraries to do it, you would compile your project for prod. You don't have to use JSX but it's recommended as it looks much nicer and cleaner - almost like html so it's easy to read and more concise

Comment: I don't think you understand what jsx actually is. [JSX in Depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html). [JSX Specification](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/).

Comment: no, you don't need to use JSX. most do, but it's not required to use react.

Comment: As to whether or not this is the right way to use React in a production environment: we transpile our source into a single `bundle.js` file which we include in our `index.html`. This gives you the additional benefit of minification, linting, etc through your build process. It is also much faster as @DominicTobias pointed out. Please do not include your code as is in a critical production system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

> You don't have to use JSX with React. You can just use plain JS. However, we recommend using JSX because it is a concise and familiar syntax for defining tree structures with attributes.

In my experience, JSX is much easier to understand at a glance and greatly improves the react experience.

You should not include the browser.min.js script in a production environment because that will require transpiling the code every time the page is loaded. Instead follow this [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) and use Webpack/Babel/Browserify to convert the code and then deploy it.